# create a custom async function (that is not calling another .net async method)

Tags: c#, .net

seems that all async examples end up calling a .net async method,

is it possible to create a custom `async` method that is not calling a .net `async` method ?

this is where I got so far:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        TestAsync();
    }

    public async void TestAsync()
    {
        await DoStuffAsync(1);

        Task.Run(() => DoStuffAsync(73));

        await Task.WhenAll(DoStuffAsync(2), DoStuffAsync(3));
    }

    public async Task DoStuffAsync(int n)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("done stuff " + n);
    }
```

the only problem with this is that VS says that async keyword in DoStuffAsync is useless (cuz there's no await), but I don't need await, I just need the possibility to await this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of the `async` keyword is to enable the `await` keyword. An `async` method without an `await` doesn't make much sense, hence the compiler warning.

You can implement a `Task`-returning method without `async`, as such:

```
public Task DoStuffAsync(int n)
{
  return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

If you want to create your own `Task`s from scratch, use `Task.Run` or `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (or one of its shortcuts such as `Task.FromResult` or `TaskFactory.FromAsync`).

P.S. You generally want to avoid `async void`; use `async Task` instead.

Comment: Note `Task.FromResult` != `Task.Run`. `Task.FromResult(Foo())` will block and `Task.Run(() => Foo())`  will not block. Also `async void` is intended for async event hanlders. `async void mybutton_click(..)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public async void TestAsync()
{
    await DoStuffAsync(1);

    await DoStuffAsync(73);

    await Task.WhenAll(DoStuffAsync(2), DoStuffAsync(3));
}

public async Task DoStuffAsync(int n)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("done stuff " + n);
}
```